# Why do we need reset_index() after a group by in Pandas and what would happen if I don't add it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

[python beginner here]
I was reading some posts on how to perform a group by on a dataframe and came across concept of resetting the index.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52299323/19158839

In the above link, the answer by user Raunaq Jain states that "Also, you will have to reset the index".

Why is there such an obligation and what would happen in case one does not do that?

There are many wonderful posts on SO to elaborate that but I believe I am lacking some fundamental knowledge to even understand the answers. I would really appreciate if one can point me to relevant resources to understand this concept better.

Thanks.

Comment: No, it is not necessary. Only obviously need final ouput without MultiIndex, so is used `.reset_index` or `as_index=False` parameter like in linked first answer.

Comment: I know stack overflow gives answers, however, I feel for this particular case, reading the documentation would be helpful

Comment: @jezrael I see, thanks for clarifying that it is not a necessity.

Comment: @sammywemmy I agree with you on that but since I began learning python just recently, I found the actual documentation a bit overwhelming and could not understand the application of the concept of index on a dataframe. Hence thought of asking on stack overflow!

Answer (score 1):

when we make a DataFrame and manipulate it by joining new column or two different tables, they both have same index like 0,1,2 from Ist table and 0,1,2 from other table. so index becomes 0,1,2,0,1,2 we reset it to make 0,1,2,3,4,5.

check out myblog on data-analytics [here](https://fordataanalysts.blogspot.com/2022/05/road-map-for-being-data-analyst.html)

Comment: if use `groupby` it is different situtation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).